# Mobile subcategory dropdown on Magento mobile theme

Tags: magento, mobile, drop-down-menu, magento-1.7

we are making mobile layout for our web site, but we don't know how to edit the subcategory dropdown: which code should we add o change?

[link](http://transmog.net/iphone-simulator/mobile-web-browser-emulator-for-iphone-5.php?u=http://test.arredodesignonline.com/it/tavoli-sedie.html)

(the dropdown that starts with the word "sedie")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Activate developer mode and template hints on your page to see witch Phtml is used in this case.

So you can make your own theme.

See [here](http://www.classyllama.com/development/magento-development/enable-templateblock-hints-in-admin-panel)